# htaccess rewrite stopped working after a while

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 sites:

```
site1.ru
site2.ru
```

It is necessary to implement such a scheme, to site1.ru/kv/ was called site2.ru without url rewrite

I have previously used such a structure

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/kv 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.ru/login.aspx [L,P]
```

but for unknown reasons it stopped working by itself, and reason can not understand (the second server is running on iis within the local visibility)

Comment: do you have `RewriteEngine on` before them? In which context they are? Describe at least what happens instead of the redirection.

Comment: yes, I have. When I log in on http://site2.ru/login.aspx happen redirect on site2.ru/Default.aspx but when i look from site1.ru/kvp login page open correctly but redirect on default happened with error because it redirecting on site1.ru/Default.aspx url

On the second server is the relative forwarding in web config

Comment: So your rewrite is working perfectly. You could modify your rewritecond like this: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(kv|Default.aspx)` and try again

Comment: big thanks! its dont work but I use proxy on every file on 2nd server. Its done for my task